# Newbie Issue About JavaScript OnFocus

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, onfocus

I have to add a default grey text in a text field of an ASP.net page like this:

[image: Image01]

And when the user clicks/enters a field, the default text disappears.

How to perform this in text box event?

I manage to implement onFocus event for changing text color; In my `.aspx` page I create a `<script>` tag for JS Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test(obj) {
        obj.style.color = "grey";
    }
</script>
```

Code behind:

```
txtBox.Attributes.Add("OnFocus", "test(this)")
'txtBox is the ID of text Box
```

Now that embarrassing asking very basic question about JavaScript OnFocus event.

But *Question is a key of knowledge* :)

**Edit:** I must not use any HTML tag in my ASP.Net Page

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: if you can use jQuery it would be far more easier for you to learn it.
http://api.jquery.com/focusin/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try using jQuery**

How to implement jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

html:

```
<input type="text" />
```

css:

```
.grey { color:#aaa; }
```

jQuery:

```
var inputval = "";
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Define your default value to show on input
    $("input[type='text']").val("Enter your text here...");
    // Add grey color or optionally blur effect
    $("input[type='text']").addClass('grey');
    // Save your default value
    inputval = $("input[type='text']").val();
    $("input[type='text']").focusin(function() {
    // if textbox is empty or got the default value
    if ($(this).val() == "" || $(this).val() == inputval) {
        // Clear the box
        $(this).val("");
        // Remove grey color
        $(this).removeClass('grey'); }
    }).focusout(function() {
        // if textbox is empty
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            // Put your Default value back
            $(this).val(inputval);
            // Add grey color
            $(this).addClass('grey'); }
    });
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BerkerYuceer/SWc6g/

this is actually a really bad coding but it should make you understand how this works.

**Edit:** Here is more efficent version

html:

```
<input type="text" />
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Watermark("input[type='text']","Enter your text here...");
});

function Watermark(element, WatermarkString) {
    $(element).val(WatermarkString).css('color','#aaa');
    $(element).focusin(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "" || $(this).val() == WatermarkString) {
            $(this).val("").css('color','#000'); }
    }).focusout(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            $(this).val(WatermarkString).css('color','#aaa'); }
    });
};
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BerkerYuceer/vLJ2U/

Comment: Wow, thanks Berker. your fiddle work for me, although I didn't use Jquery till now, but now its helps me. Thanks again

Comment: You cud have just added just this, instead: `$("#textbox").attr("placeholder", "Enter text here...");`

Comment: @PraveenKumar nice catch, though i didnt look carefully xD +1

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to generate something like this?

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your text here..." />
```

So you need to actually add this `placeholder="Enter your text here..."` attribute to the `<input />` tag.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't have to use any HTML tag in my aspx page (Management restriction)

Comment: txtBox.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Enter your text here...")

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you meant to do?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <input id="serachbox" type="text" onFocus="initText(this);" />

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var defaultText = 'Enter your serach here...'
        var initText = function(el){
            if(el.value == defaultText){
                el.value = "";
            }
        }

        var input = document.getElementById('serachbox');

        input.value = defaultText;
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about ASP.NET, but since you can add an onfocus listener, you should be able to do something like:

```
txtBox.Attributes.Add("Value", "Enter your text here...")
txtBox.Attributes.Add("OnFocus", "updateValue(this)")
txtBox.Attributes.Add("OnBlur", "updateValue(this)")
```

where the updateValue function is:

```
function updateValue(el) {
    if (el.value == el.defaultValue) {
      el.value = '';
    } else {
      el.value = el.defaultValue;
    }
}
```

The above mimics the placeholder attribute, which (IMO) is an annoying interface feature that should rarely be used.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for **watermark** effect in a text field?

If so, there are a couple ways to do it.

1) use [AjaxToolKit](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/87024) libraray ([Watermark Effect Demo Here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/TextBoxWatermark/TextBoxWatermark.aspx)) 
2) use HTML + CSS + jQuery

```
<input type="text" id="text1" value="some text"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var tbval = $('#text1').val();
    $('#text1').focus(function() { $(this).val('');});
    $('#text1').blur(function() { $(this).val(tbval);});
  });
</script>
```

Source:

- http://blogs.planetcloud.co.uk/mygreatdiscovery/post/A-simple-jQuery-watermark-textbox.aspx
- http://www.misfitgeek.com/textbox-input-watermark-using-jquery/